# Where does logstash persist state?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I want to leverage logstash and the [Csv filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-csv.html) to watch a directory for new files and process them into Elasticsearch. This is easily achievable with a configuration similar to this:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/csv/*.csv"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}

filter {
    csv {
        separator => ","
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "${ELASTICSEARCH_URL}"
        index => "myData"
        document_type => "auto"
    }
}
```

My main concern is **Resiliency** and **Integrity**.

**Resiliency** - I watched the talk by [João Duarte](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mfb0R7azKZc) where he explains the challenges with this over a year ago. He explains that logstash (at that time) held all state in memory and wasn't resilient to failure. Is this still true? He alludes to potentially storing state in a file, does this file exist now? If logstash crashes in the middle of reading a Csv file I need it to continue where it left off when it restarts. Is this possible?

**Integrity** - After a fair amount of Googling it seems that [Logstash is still incapable of deleting (or renaming) the Csv file after it's read](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/delete-a-log-file-after-indexing-via-logstash/41239/2). My data may not be idempotent and I can not tolerate reading the same Csv twice. It seems however, that logstash doesn't continue to try and read the same file over and over so there is some mechanism there to prevent reading the same file (at least immediately). What strategy is advised at this time to "do something" after a Csv file is read (delete, rename, move), and if this is not possible then what is the best-practice for cleaning up the csv files because they can't hang around forever.

Comment: Not sure why this got a down-vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Persistent Queues](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.2/persistent-queues.html) have been in the code since 5.2, and by 5.6 they're considered production quality. This will persist events in the pipeline to a local file, that will be read at restart.

As for not rereading files, this has been a core part of Logstash for years. The mechanism for this is called `sincedb`, and the file plugin you've specified has sincedb parameters to configure it. `sincedb_path` specifies the sincedb_file itself that will be used, and `sincedb_write_interval` specifies how often it updates the database with file offsets.

For cleaning up your files, Logstash definitely does not provide a mechanism for that and intentionally leaves that up to the operator. There are a variety of mechanisms for this, only one of which is a cron job that runs something like the following once an hour:

```
find /var/log/csv-archive/ -atime 0.083 -type f |xargs rm
```

For removing all files that haven't been accessed in an hour. There are other methods for this.